# ActionScript - Get Instance Name From Constructor Without Passing Parameters?

Tags: actionscript-3, constructor, instance

is it possible to obtain the instance name of a class from the class without having to manually pass the instance name as a string parameter to the class constructor?

```
//Create New SizeClass
var big:SizeClass = new SizeClass();

//-------------

package
{
public class SizeClass
     {
     public function SizeClass()
          {
          trace( //-- Instance Name "big" --// );
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to know anything about the containing code block during a constructor, save what you can learn from the stack trace (though that's not available except in the debugger version of Flash).  Even if you had a global access point for the containing class, it still would not allow for that access.

Think of a constructor like a method call.  In a line of AS, it will be called *before* the assignment.  Eg: `var a:Foo = new Foo()` the `Foo` is created (the constructor completes), and then `a` is populated with whatever just happened.  After that point `a` will remain agnostic of its context (because of encapsulation) unless it is told about it (this is even true on a DisplayObject -- try this( `var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); trace( mc.root ) //this will be null` ).

---

I'm keeping this because it is useful albeit not useful to your original answer.

You can always get the name of a class with `getQualifiedClassName` from the `flash.utils` package.  You can't get a DisplayObject's until well after it has been constructed, but you can simulate this by (I believe) overriding `function set name( value:String ):void`.  If that doesn't work, then try finding it after `Event.ADDED` and/or `Event.ADDED_TO_SAGE`.

Answer (score 1):

The instance name isn't very important. You'd better store references of the instances inside an array.

```
var sizes:Array = new Array();
var big:SizeClass = new SizeClass();
sizes.push( big );
```

When you want to access them, you can loop through the array.

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < list.length; ++i) 
{
    var size:SizeClass = list[i] as SizeClass;
    trace( size );
}
```

BTW: Instead of an instance name it is possible to add an automatic index to your class.

```
package
{
  public class SizeClass 
  {
    private static var global_index:int = 0;
    public const INDEX:int = global_index ++;
  }
}
```

Which you can access like this:

```
var big:SizeClass = new SizeClass();
trace(big.INDEX) // 0

var small:SizeClass = new SizeClass();
trace(small.INDEX)// 1
```

source: http://blog.stroep.nl/2010/08/auto-increment-as3-class/

Comment: i'm writing a class for my own library, and referencing the instance name would be a huge convenience, even though i'm aware it's probably not the best design.